# Which octave does Cb4 belong to?

Tags: notation

How do you distinguish:

- C tone in 4th octave - flat
- Cb in 4th octave
  ?

Or said other way around. Is the order of operations: (C4)b or (Cb)${calculate octave}?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Scientific pitch notation** is one way to determine specific notes. It goes from C>B, as in C3 is the note one semitone higher that B2, C4 one semitone higher than B3.

All notes which are around C4 come into the C4 category. As in C, C♭, C♮, C♯ and Cx (aka ♯♯).

Had the note in question, C4♭ been called a B, it would be B3. That same B, sharpened to B♯ would be called B3♯.The sign should go above, the octave number under it.

So the answer is C4♭. 246.94 Hz taken when A4=440Hz.

Comment: I had never heard of Cx meaning C double sharp before. That was a bit tricky to confirm.

Comment: Unlike double flat, double sharp has its own sign rather than a repeated regular sharp sign.  Lower case x is an approximation to this, like using b for flat or # for sharp.

Comment: @BitChaser I edited; the proper symbols are  ♭ ♮ ♯  (Unicode 1d12b, 266d, 266e, 266f, 1d12a). I'm not sure the double-flat and double-sharp will render correctly on all systems. A better ASCII/markdown-approximation on StackExchange might be to use `<sup>**x**</sup>` or `&times;`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - thanks, but what looks more like an asterix isn't as effective - in my opinion - as an 'x' - which after all, is exactly what we expect in the dots. I'm reverting! I dare say if it looked like the changed sign, it would still have fooled Bit Chaser!

Comment: Strange that it looks like an asterisk to you, but yeah, as I said I'm not surprised that  renders inconsistently across platforms. Still, I think plain ASCII `x` is most confusing (absent your “aka ♯♯” clarification). Some other alternatives to try: C×, C✕, C❌, C, C. Hm,  think C× (`C&times;`) is probably the best and should definitely render quite reliably.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - not had any negative feedback about it till now, and others use it and it's clear. Just think Bit Chaser hadn't met 'x' in any of its incarnations before...

Comment: `&times;` clearly has a totally different semantics. IMHO, we should produce the correct semantics first, before we have a look how it renders.

Comment: Thanks @Tim!
As a conclusion, can we say that C4b = Cb3 = B3?

Comment: We can say just that - and we'd be wrong! Please read the answer very carefully.

Comment: I understand. Cb3 would mean Cb in the third octave. I had wrong understanding of the way how you could write notes in chromatic scale. So I thought you can write it as (using flats):
C, Db, D, Eb, E, F, Gb, G, Ab, A, Bb, B, with the C flat from the next octave being Cb in the current one.

Comment: What’s the reason we name our notes from A (the no accidental _minor_ key), but scientific pitch notation loops at _C_?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - there is a special place to ask questions..!

Answer (score 5):

It's a flattened C4.   Sounding the same as B3, admittedly!

One of the many instances in music notation where 'spelling matters'.